# Export MYSQL Database to Excel in C# Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, mysql, excel

I am using c# windows forms application where I am using MySQL DB, my requirement is to export complete table data in Excel format. Please tell me how it is possible.
I am using following code to save my data in MYSQL DB

```
    private void insert_data()
    {
        string MyConnection2= "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=abc;password=xyz";

        string Query = "";
        reset_data();
        Query = "INSERT INTO test_data.display_only(Article_ID ,Article_Name ,Manufacturer,Article_Quantity) SELECT Article_ID,Article_Name ,Manufacturer,Article_Quantity FROM _data.entered_items";
        MySqlConnection MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection2); 
        MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(Query, MyConn2);
        MySqlDataReader MyReader2;
        MyConn2.Open();
        MyReader2 = MyCommand2.ExecuteReader();     
        MessageBox.Show("Data Updated");
        while (MyReader2.Read())
       {
       }
        MyConn2.Close();
    }
```

Comment: you want to create excel file with Article_ID ,Article_Name ,Manufacturer etc details.Get the existing DB table data to datatable and then insert the latest data into the datatable and excel at sametime.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find plenty of ways to export database to excel by a simple Google search. For EX: You can use excel.interop if Excel is installed: [How to export databse to excel file](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-export.htm). Other alternative ways without having Excel installed: [Solutions to Export Data From Database to Excel in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/83fe73/solutions-to-export-data-from-database-to-excel-in-C-Sharp/) or export to excel using Open XML SDK.